# Vim: How to enter a normal editor command in shell before literally oppening

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys, vim, text

There is a command option when you run vim to open a file with command-line that i found when i was searching. here it is:

```
vim "+ normal G" textfile
```

When you use the command `+ normal G` vim opens the file and presses <kbd>G</kbd> in normal mode. I wanted this in my custom script. Now I need to pgdn when I start the file automatically. Its editor command in vim is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. I test options like `vim "+ normal ^f" textfile` and `vim "+ normal CTRL-f" textfile` but it didn't work.
Anyone know how can I state <kbd>CTRL</kbd> in it?

Comment: Use `vim "+20" filename` instead.

Comment: Consider using [vi.se] for questions on Vim!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Vim's [`:execute`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute) command, which executes an Ex command from a string, and that allows you to enter a special key using a `\<...>` inside a double quoted string.

```
$ vim '+ execute "normal \<C-f>"' textfile
```